Under what conditions of $A$ with $A^r=I$ do we have that $\sqrt[n]A=e^{i\frac{\pi}{rn}(I-A)},\:n=1,2,3,\ldots?$
Muradian and Frias give a number of simple relations for a matrix and its exponential, with focus on self-inverse matrices $A$ where $A=A^{-1}$ and $A^2=I$.  They show that for such involutory matrices, $$
\sqrt[n]{\!A} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2n}(I-A)},\quad n=1,2,3,\ldots
$$
Most of Muradian and Frias's results are a simple consequence of Euler's identity:
$$e^{\pm i\alpha A}=I\cos \alpha\pm A\sin \alpha\tag 1.$$
I have been interested in non-self-inverse matrices, where we know the degree $r\ne 2$ of the minimal polynomial such that $A^r=I$.
In particular is true that for the $n^{th}$ root of $A$ we have:
$$
\sqrt[n]{\!A} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{rn}(I-A)}, 
\quad n=1,2,3,\ldots?\tag 2$$
Or does this only apply when $A$ is an involution and $r=2$?

Have you tried $A = 2 I$?

@RobertIsrael Indeed no, I hadn't.  Are you saying that $e^{i\pi 2 I}=e^{i\pi I}e^{i\pi I}=I\ne-I$?

Yes, I am saying that.

Thanks! Then under what conditions on $A$ is $e^{i\pi A}=\pm I$ or some other root of the identity?

If $A$ has a complete set of eigenvectors and its eigenvalues are all integer multiples of $1/k$, then the eigenvalues of $\exp(i\pi A)$ are all $2k$'th roots of unity, and $\left(\exp(i\pi A)\right)^{2k} = I$.

I guess if $A$ is a permutation, it itself is unitary already the eigenvalues have unit norm a priori…
